# Download files in Javascript with OAuth2

Tags: oauth, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I'm developing an single-page with Javascript+AngularJS on the client side and Spring MVC + Spring Security OAuth2 on the server side. Spring MVC acts as a REST controller for any AJAX requests from the page.

For authorization, the script sends an "Authorization: Bearer ..." headers with each AJAX request. This works fine when requesting small amounts of data.
To download XML files (export user data) I download them via AJAX, using the OAuth2 headers and create a Blob to allow saving the file in the browser:

```
var blob = new Blob([data.data], {'type': "text/xml"});
var a = document.createElement("a");
a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
a.download = "downloaded-file-" + new Date().toISOString() + ".xml";
a.click();
```

This approach works but

- Uses RAM and so is unsuitable for large file downloads
- Does not show a proper progress/loading bar

So, the question is: is there a better way of downloading files with OAuth2 authorization? Javascript does not allow to specify headers when doing redirects, and OAuth does not allow to specify the authorization token via URL parameters. I'm thinking of either

- adding a special Spring MVC controller method to provide an URL which  redirects from an URL-encoded token to a header-encoded HTTP request
- adding an extra Spring Security filter to allows extracting the token from URL parameters
- moving to cookie-based authorization instead of OAuth2

If anyone had similar issues, could you please share your approach to this problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Turns out it's very easy to to in spring-security-oauth2 2.0.7.RELEASE:

Simply pass the access token as the `access_token` request parameter:

```
window.open("service/export?access_token=" + access_token);
```

Now, this will appear with the access token in plaintext in the download history, so for proper security a "logout" option should be properly implemented, or the download will have to be done as a "form post".

Comment: nice to know this feature. One question, what do you mean with "a logout option should be properly implemented"?

Comment: The URL will be kept in the browser's history along with the token. Anyone who has access to the browser's history will be able to find the URL and extract the access_token value. So in case a user logs in from a public computer, he needs to be able to log out (destroy/forget the access_token on the server side), otherwise anyone will be able to use his access_token until it expires. Spring doesn't offer a "logout" feature,  so unless tokens are short-lived, a feature need to be implemented to erase the access_token on the server side.

Comment: Dmitry Zolotukhin is right, do not pass access token as request param. Here is a link from OAuth documentation:  https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6750#section-5.3 
Don't pass bearer tokens in page URLs: Bearer tokens SHOULD NOT be
passed in page URLs (for example, as query string parameters).
Instead, bearer tokens SHOULD be passed in HTTP message headers or
message bodies for which confidentiality measures are taken.
Browsers, web servers, and other software may not adequately
secure URLs in the browser history, web server logs...

Comment: Remember that the `Spring Security OAuth` project is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with cookies if I were you - it takes all the hassle out of it. I wrote some blogs recently to show how easy it is (e.g. https://spring.io/blog/2015/01/20/the-resource-server-angular-js-and-spring-security-part-iii). People get too hung up on "stateless" applications.

Comment: what would be your solution to prevent xsrf in this situation?

Comment: Spring Security and Spring Security OAuth both have anti xsrf (we call it "csrf") measures that are on by default. If you have a particular concern I would raise that as a separate question.

Comment: But if the cookie is coming from an external source how are you providing the token for xsrf prevention is what I'm curious about.