# Angular: how to download file without showing access_token in url

Tags: angularjs, spring, oauth, access-token

My web application is secured by Oauth2. For ajax calls, the access_token has to be provided in the request folder. For example, here is one of the methods in factory.js:

```
   service.getAll = function () {
        var url = SERVER + "/ristore/foundation/";
        return $http({
            headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + $window.localStorage.getItem("access_token")},
            url: url,
            method: 'GET',
            crossOrigin: true
        })
    }
```

Now I would like to download a file from the webpage. The file is passed to client from server with streaming:

```
@RequestMapping(
        value = "/ristore/foundation/xml/{filename}",
        method = RequestMethod.GET,
        produces = "application/xml")
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> downloadXMLFile(@PathVariable String filename) throws IOException {
    FileSystemResource xmlFile = new FileSystemResource("/rsrch1/rists/moonshot/data/prod/foundation/xml/" + filename + ".xml");
    byte [] content = new byte[(int)xmlFile.contentLength()];
    IOUtils.read(xmlFile.getInputStream(), content);

    return ResponseEntity.ok()
        .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/octet-stream"))
        .contentLength(xmlFile.contentLength())
        .body(content);
}
```

In html, I specify the ng-click() on the button that will be clicked to start downloading:

```
        <td data-title="'File'" class="text-center"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt" ng-click="download(report.filename)"></span></a>
            </td>
```

Based on the answer to this post [Download files in Javascript with OAuth2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28384470/download-files-in-javascript-with-oauth2), `$window.open` is used to handle the url in my controller:

```
  $scope.download = function(filename) {
        var url = "http://rcdrljboss01a:9880/ristoreService/ristore/foundation/xml/" + filename + "?access_token=" + $window.localStorage.getItem("access_token");
        $window.open(url);
    }
```

I am able to download file this way, but the access_token is shown in the downloading url. Is there a way to hide the access_token in the url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put the access token in the header instead of in the query parameter.

This [tutorial](http://www.baeldung.com/rest-api-spring-oauth2-angularjs) shows how this works in detail.

Edit : Is there a way to add the token to the header of wondow.open(..) ?

No, it seems not to be possible to directly change the header for window.open(..)

What you can do :

Get the xml with ajax, open a new window and set the file as content of the window (pseudo code, you may need to convert the content to string):

```
var win = open('some-url','windowName','height=300,width=300');
win.document.write(content);
```

Comment: I did put access_token in header for all other requests like the post. But now I am using $window.open for the url. If there is a way to use header for that, I would have done so.