# Download large files securely using JWT

Tags: angular, http, security, download, jwt

we have an angular project using JWT as the way of authentication with the API

it all works fine except for downloading files (it can be very large eg. 10 GB)

i read the [Download files in Javascript with OAuth2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28384470/download-files-in-javascript-with-oauth2)
 suggesting that we should pass the token as query param

but when i googled it i found this isn't recommended in many sites and i'm wondering what is the alternatives

so is there more secure solution to download the files than passing it in the query param?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Similarily to AWS S3 signed url, I suggest you generate a special JWT token just to download the file and pass it using query param:

1) Client calls `POST /request-download/[fileID]` - to request authorization to download the file.

2) Server returns special JWT just for downloading the file in the response

3) Client downloads file using `GET /path-to-file?token=[the-token-from-response]`

You just need to implement custom authentication/authorization logic on the server to accept the special JWT token for the file.

You can skip the 1st step and just return the specilal file donwload token for download with each file.

What I mean by "Special JWT token to download the file" is a standard JWT token, which authorizes the holder only to download the single file, nothing else - you can pass the `fileId` as a claim into the token, set the expiration time to match your needs. Then you can verify the token validity on the download endpoint. easily.

Comment: what do you mean by "special JWT just for downloading the file" and "signed token for download with each file"

Comment: What I mean by "Special JWT token to download the file" is a standard JWT token, which authorizes the holder only to download the single file, nothing else - you can pass the `fileId` into the toke, set the expiration time to match your needs. Then you can verify the token validity on the download endpoint easily.